# Função que gera arquivo

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js

Como criar uma função em javascript que gera um arquivo.ini?

Por exemplo, vou preencher 2 campos e ele vai gerar um arquivo assim

```
[teste]
nome: "campo 1 que vou preencher"
teste: teste
teste: teste
email: "campo 2 que vou preencher"
teste: teste
teste:
```

Seria só isso, aí a pessoa clica em Salvar ou Download e baixa o arquivo
Estou tentando usar o FileSaver, mas tô com problema até para executar a demo dele

tentei de outro jeito também mais ou menos assim

```
$('#salvar').click(function() {
    var nome = $('#nome').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    this.href = "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(texto);
});
```

Comment: Queres gerar o conteúdo no JavaScript e fazer com que quando o utilizador clicar seja iniciado um download com um ficheiro, é isso?

Comment: Isso, por exemplo, o usuário preenche dois campos e ao clicar em Salvar/Download, será feito o download do arquivo.ini para ele com os dados padrões do arquivos + os dados que ele preencher
Estou quebrando a cabeça para tentar criar um modelo que funcione assim

Comment: A tag `node.js` não se aplica a esta pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma abordagem diferente seria criar um [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Blob) com os valores. Após isso, basta realizar o download.

Um exemplo da utilização seria assim:

```js
function baixarArquivo() {
  var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

  var texto = '[teste]\n' +
    'nome: ' + nome + '\n' +
    'teste: teste\n' +
    'teste: teste\n' +
    'email: ' + email + '\n' +
    'teste: teste\n' +
    'teste:';

  var fileName = 'arquivo.txt';
  var fileContent = texto;

  var arquivo = new Blob([fileContent], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });

  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  document.getElementById('download').setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(arquivo));
  document.getElementById('download').setAttribute('download', fileName);
}
```

```html
Nome: <input id="nome" />
<br/>
E-mai: <input id="email" />
<br/>
<a href="" id="download" onclick="baixarArquivo();">Download</a>
```

Lembrando que você pode alterar a extensão no nome do arquivo.

[Referência](http://www.tutsandtips.com/javascript/how-to-download-a-text-file-with-javascript/)

Comment: Eu queria entender melhor o primeiro parâmetro de `Blob`. Por que você declarou um objeto nele? Enfim, parece uma boa alternativa

Comment: @nicematt O primeiro parâmetro é um `Array` e derivados. O que é aceito você pode ver melhor [na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#Parameters). Caso queira, faço uma explicação mais detalhada na resposta mais tarde.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso que eu estava tentando entender, agora vou tentar fazer o arquivo vir no formato do modelo que falei. grato!

Comment: Não precisava de `setAttribute` para definir `HTMLElement().download` e `HTMLElement().href`, né

Answer (score 3):

```js
function download(filename, nome, email) {
  var element = document.createElement('a')
  element['href'] = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(nome + '\n' + email)
  element['download'] = filename

  element['style']['display'] = 'none'
  document['body']['appendChild'](element)

  element['click']()

  document['body']['removeChild'](element)
}
```

```css
form * {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="download(this['arquivo'].value, this['nome'].value, this['email'].value)">
  <input type="text" id="arquivo" value="teste.txt">
  <input type="text" id="nome" name="Nome">
  <input type="text" id="email" name="E-Mail">     
  <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197341/1997073

Comment: @nicematt fique a vontade para editar a resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta também, me ajudou da mesma forma, só fiquei um pouco mais confuso para criar o modelo do arquivo

Comment: @João +1 pelo feedback! :)